# Получить все числа, не превышающие заданного числа N, которые делятся без остатка на все свои цифрыы

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Накопал в интернете эту ссылку:
https://clck.ru/JccbR
Здесь написано на C++, попытался перевести на Питон, в соразмерности со своими знаниями, получил:

```
def test(i):
    k = i
    while(k):
        d = k % 10
        k /= 10
        if (d and i % d):
            return False
    return True
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if (test(i)):
        print(i)
```

Программа ничего не выводит, подскажите пожалуйста где я не прав?

Comment: Дело в том, что я не совсем понимаю как работает код, поэтому попросил помощи либо что-либо поправить, либо просто объяснить, что не так. Если я 'return False' заменю на 'return True', то программа будет выводить все числа до N

Comment: попробуйте заменить `k /= 10` на целочисленное деление - `k //= 10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Python 3.x:

```
k /= 10
```

Вернет число с плавающей точкой.

Воспользуйтесь целочисленным делением:

```
k //= 10
```

---

```
def test(i):
    k = i
    while(k):
        d = k % 10
        k //= 10
        if (d == 0 or i % d):
            return False
    return True
```

проверка:

```
In [174]: for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
     ...:     if (test(i)):
     ...:         print(i)
     ...:
42

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
15
22
24
33
36
```

Comment: Почти, заработало. Теперь выводит 10, 20, 30 и тд. Не подскажите(да это уже наглость)))) как сделать проверку?

Comment: `if (d and i % d):` - здесь достаточно `if i % d:`. А вообще, можно оба if'а объединить в один: `if d == 0 or i % d:`

Comment: @MaxU, так там не может быть нуля - он у тебя на две строчки выше проверен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мда, торможжуу...)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена, как и сказал @MaxU нужно было заменить `k/=10` на `k//=10`, а также сделать проверку на круглое число:
def test(i):

```
    k = i
    while(k):
        d = k % 10
        k //= 10
        if (d and i % d):
            return False
    return True
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if (test(i) and i % 10 != 0):
        print(i)
```

Большое спасибо)